# How to update multiple tables in database(Django) using single .csv file?

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, django-models

[Table Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CahR.png)
I want to distribute the data of above table into multiple tables.
Say :-
Product name and Company goes into 1st table.
Barcode and Price goes into 2nd table.
Category and Subcategory goes into 3rdtable.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to solve your problem would be to implement a custom management command, you can check the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/). You could parse the CSV and then update the specific entries on your database.

The usage would be something like this (assuming for example that the command is called `updateproducts`):

> $ python manage.py updateproducts path/to/your/file.csv

Of course that depending on the size of your data, other approaches might be more efficient.